# a jinja variable for flask-app root directory

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have been developing an app using the very easy-to-pickup [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) system and I have used a jinja template to write out a bunch of links that correspond to pages in Flask that are defined by something like this:

```
@app.route(/<var1>/<var2>)
...
...
```

in the test server these links work just fine however when I move from the test server to a server behind a proxy I get a problem where the href links don't take into account the extra directory name inserted by my proxy.

```
#where a link should read:
server:/myapp/<var1>/<var2>
# it acually puts out:
server:/<var1>/<var2>
```

my jinja etemplate looks like this but I am wondering if instead of putting a backslash there is a way to put a variable that specifies root directory.

```
{% block navigation %}
{% for record in db.values() %}
 <li><a href="/{{db.name}}/{{record.name}}">{{record.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Flask team!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, as @reclosedev said, you can generate URLs using the [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#url-building) function (assuming the view function is called `myview`:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('myview', var1=db.name, var2=record.name) }}">
```

Secondly, if you're behind a reverse proxy, wrap the WSGI application with [this decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/) that updates the request environment so that Flask generates correct URLs.

Comment: thanks alex, I am actually using that snippet but I the links I generated in my template didn't update with the new locations.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) function?

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('view_func_name', 
                        var1=db.name, 
                        var2=record.name) }}">{{record.name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Also, if you're behind a reverse proxy, check out [this flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/).

Comment: @AlexMorega, probably this snippet is the solution for OP's problem and I think it should be posted as answer.